# Why doesn't Grails Scaffolding list all members of my domain object?

Tags: grails, groovy, scaffolding

Domain Object:

```
class User {

    static constraints = {
    }

    String name
    Locale locale
    List reports
    static hasMany = [reports: Report]

    String toString(){
        return name
    }
}
```

And Controller:

```
class UserController {

     def scaffold = User
}
```

The auto-generated index page shows only two columns; name and locale. I want it to also show a list of reports. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

The Grails Scaffolding Plugin does not auto generate collections. You have to implement the rendering of the collection (in your case a list) in your `index.gsp` yourself

Comment: Does that mean I have to generate all the view files for the project, or can I just "override" the index.gsp for the User domain object?

Comment: If only index.gsp is your problem you have to override only that